# prometheus CollectAndCount always returns 1

Tags: unit-testing, go, prometheus

I want to instrument a program and check with tests if the instrumentation had been done properly. I discovered the testutil which has a function called CollectAndCount. I expect that the function returns the same count I would see on the HTTP metric endpoint. When I increase the counter in the example below 2 times the CollectAndCount returns 1 and not as expected 2. It would be feasible to use in this case the ToFloat64 function. As I want to get the count for a histogram too the ToFloat64 is not available.

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/testutil"
)

func TestMetricT(t *testing.T) {
    var Duration = prometheus.NewHistogram(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
        Name:    "duration",
        Help:    "Help",
        Buckets: prometheus.DefBuckets,
    })

    var Errors = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "errors",
        Help: "Help",
    })

    prometheus.MustRegister(Duration, Errors)

    timer := prometheus.NewTimer(Duration)
    timer.ObserveDuration()
    Errors.Inc()

    timer = prometheus.NewTimer(Duration)
    timer.ObserveDuration()

    Errors.Inc()

    errors := testutil.CollectAndCount(Errors)
    if errors != 2 {
        t.Error("no 2 increments but", errors, "ToFloat64 counts", testutil.ToFloat64(Errors))
    }

    observations := testutil.CollectAndCount(Duration)
    if observations != 2 {
        t.Error("not 2 observations but", observations)
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
--- FAIL: TestMetricT (0.00s)
    so_test.go:35: no 2 increments but 1 ToFloat64 counts 2
    so_test.go:40: not 2 observations but 1
FAIL
FAIL
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution. Furthermore, I did not take the time to open an issue on their issue tracker or check if it is resolved in newer versions.

If you have more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used slightly different metrics than your example to illustrate what is happening and I've also decided to use testify to get a more compact example. Feel free to ask if there are any questions left.

---

**TL;DR:** `CollectAndCount` returns the number of metrics that were collected, `ToFloat64` retruns the actual value of a single metric.

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/testutil"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestMetricT(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)

    var A = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "A",
        Help: "Help",
    })

    var B = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "B",
        Help: "Help",
    })

    // CounterVec is a Collector that bundles a set of Counters
    var C = prometheus.NewCounterVec(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "C",
        Help: "Help",
    }, []string{"subname"},
    )

    prometheus.MustRegister(A, B, C)

    // After the registration, simple metrics like A and B can
    // be collected with the CollectAndCount function.
    // The CollectAndCount function seems to count the number of
    // metrics which were collected, not their value.
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(A))
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(B))
    // Different to the "simple" metrics like the counters A and B,
    // C is a CounterVec, a collection of counters that share
    // the same description.
    // After its registration, this collection contains 0 metrics,
    // until one is added to the collection.
    assert.Equal(0, testutil.CollectAndCount(C))

    // ToFloat64 returns the actual value of the metric. After the
    // registration, the value of the counters A and B is 0.
    assert.Equal(float64(0), testutil.ToFloat64(A))
    assert.Equal(float64(0), testutil.ToFloat64(B))

    A.Inc()
    B.Inc()

    // After we incremented A and B, CollectAndCount still
    // collects exactly one metric series for A, and one for B.
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(A))
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(B))
    // But the actual values of the counters were incremented by 1.
    assert.Equal(float64(1), testutil.ToFloat64(A))
    assert.Equal(float64(1), testutil.ToFloat64(B))

    A.Inc()
    B.Inc()

    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(A))
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(B))
    // Now we incremented the counters again, and ToFloat64
    // returns 2, since we've incremented each counter 2 times.
    assert.Equal(float64(2), testutil.ToFloat64(A))
    assert.Equal(float64(2), testutil.ToFloat64(B))

    A.Inc()

    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(A))
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(B))
    // Only incremented A
    assert.Equal(float64(3), testutil.ToFloat64(A))
    assert.Equal(float64(2), testutil.ToFloat64(B))

    // To increment C, we have to use a label. This
    // adds a metric with the label "firstLabel" to the
    // collection C.
    C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel").Inc()
    // Now, CollectAndCount will collect the one metric which
    // is contained in the collection C.
    assert.Equal(1, testutil.CollectAndCount(C))
    // The ToFloat64 value of the metrics is as expected.
    // We have to again use a label here, since we cannot get a
    // single float value from a collection.
    assert.Equal(float64(1), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel")))

    // Let's increase the "firstLabel" metric again and add another one.
    C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel").Inc()
    C.WithLabelValues("secondLabel").Inc()

    // CollectAndCount now collects 2 metrics from the collection C.
    assert.Equal(2, testutil.CollectAndCount(C))
    assert.Equal(float64(2), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel")))
    assert.Equal(float64(1), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("secondLabel")))

    C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel").Inc()
    C.WithLabelValues("secondLabel").Inc()
    C.WithLabelValues("thirdLabel").Inc()

    assert.Equal(3, testutil.CollectAndCount(C))
    assert.Equal(float64(3), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("firstLabel")))
    assert.Equal(float64(2), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("secondLabel")))
    assert.Equal(float64(1), testutil.ToFloat64(C.WithLabelValues("thirdLabel")))
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't have to use `CollectAndCount` before using `ToFloat64`, since `ToFloat64` will also collect the wished metrics from the provided Collector.